# Is there possibility to export from Toon Boom Animation Harmony 16 Pro to json?

Tags: svg, animation, adobe-after-effects

I'm a developer and we want to create an animated hero for one-to-one video chat and this here will be like the third participant.
We want to get along only with css animation in extreme case start using canvas.

I like how `bodymovin` works https://codepen.io/airnan/project/full/ZeNONO but it has plugin only for Adobe After Effects but there is no plugin for Harmony 16 Pro.

Comment: This looks like a question you should ask the developers of Harmony 16 Pro

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. After a quick search of the [Toon Boom community forum](https://forums.toonboom.com/search/node/json) and a lack of answers to similar questions, I suspect the answer is no. You might be better to ask your question there, or even request it as a feature if not already implemented.